# Direct solar radiation from terrain data on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, solar-radiation

I am trying to calculate direct solar radiation on GEE, using terrain data. when I check the results in small areas Found that, the solar radiation on the north slope is significantly higher than the south slope, which is unreasonable. After I checked the change within a day, there were more negative values on the south slope,can anyone help me to check the formula?

```
var table = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[86.12699868016884, 27.959963845230117],
          [86.12699868016884, 27.751127539800084],
          [86.35496498876259, 27.751127539800084],
          [86.35496498876259, 27.959963845230117]]], null, false);
// Load the elevation and latitude datasets
// the mask of ns_aspect
var dataset = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');
var elevation = dataset.select('elevation');
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(elevation);
var aspect = ee.Terrain.aspect(elevation).updateMask(slope.gt(5));

var N_aspect =aspect.updateMask(aspect.gt(0).and(aspect.lte(45)).or(aspect.gt(315).and(aspect.lte(360))));
var S_aspect =aspect.updateMask(aspect.gt(135).and(aspect.lte(225)));
var NS_aspect = ee.ImageCollection([N_aspect,S_aspect]).mosaic();

var latitude = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude').clip(table);

// Convert latitude to radians
var latitudeRad = toRadians(latitude);

// Define the solar constant (in Watts per square meter)
var solarConstant = 1361;

// Define the Earth-Sun distance multiplier
// Define the time range of interest
var startDate = ee.Date('2022-06-01');
var endDate = ee.Date('2022-06-02');

// Calculate the time interval between each aggregation period
var intervalMinutes = 10;
var aggregationInterval = ee.Number(intervalMinutes).multiply(60).multiply(1000); // Convert minutes to milliseconds

// Create a list of dates at 10-minute intervals within the time range
var dateSequence = ee.List.sequence(startDate.millis(), endDate.millis(), aggregationInterval)
  .map(function(dateMillis) {
    return ee.Date(dateMillis);
  });
// Calculate the average direct radiation every 10 minutes
var directRadiationPer10Min = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(dateSequence.map(function(date) {
    var startTime = ee.Date(date);
    var dayOfYear = startTime.getRelative('day', 'year');
    var slopeRad =  toRadians(slope);
    var aspectRad = toRadians(aspect);
    
    //Hour angle (ω)  ω = 15° * (T - 12)
    var hourAngleRad =  toRadians(ee.Number(15).multiply(startTime.getRelative('hour', 'day').subtract(12)));
    // Calculate solar declination angle (δ) in radians  δ = 23.45° * sin(360° * (284 + N) / 365)
    var declination = toRadians(ee.Number(23.45).multiply((ee.Number(360 / 365).multiply(dayOfYear.add(284))).sin()));
        declination = ee.Image.constant(declination);
    //cos
    
    var cosincident = (latitudeRad.sin().multiply(hourAngleRad.cos()).multiply(aspectRad.cos()).multiply(slopeRad.sin()).multiply(-1)
                      .subtract(aspectRad.sin().multiply(hourAngleRad.sin()).multiply(slopeRad.sin()))
                      .add(latitudeRad.cos().multiply(hourAngleRad.cos()).multiply(slopeRad.cos()))).multiply(declination.cos())
                      .add(latitudeRad.cos().multiply(aspectRad.cos()).multiply(slopeRad.sin())
                      .add(latitudeRad.sin().multiply(slopeRad.cos()))).multiply(declination.sin());

    //Direct solar radiation on the slope (Gd) Gd = Gon * cos(β)
    var Gd = cosincident.multiply(solarConstant);
  
 
    // Set the timestamp as a property of the image
    return Gd.set('system:time_start', startTime.millis());

  })).sort('system:time_start');

  Map.addLayer(directRadiationPer10Min)

function toRadians(degrees) {
  return degrees.multiply(Math.PI / 180);
}
```